# How to align label with select in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: materialize

I'm trying to create a multiple `select` with MaterializeCSS. 
My html looks like this:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Brands</label>
</div>
```

Activate the select: `$('select').material_select();`

Unfortunately the result looks like this: 
[image: Select]

While to their examples look like [this](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select).

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem with this as well.

Make sure that your `input-field` is contained within a div with class `row` and also make sure your `input-field` has a col and size class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
    ...
```

If that doesn't work, make sure your other classes of the `form` or other divs match that of the examples on the materialize website.